# Premiere Pro: Loading Footage for Project Problem

Tags: premiere

When I open my project it loads the footage in the background. Unfortunately, it stops at a certain point (close to ready) but I can't figure out which file is causing the problem since my folder paths are too long (I am only seeing something like: *G:\Video\Projectx\scene1(footage)...*). When I open the project it shows me this error message: *Video Filter missing: AE.ADBE Aud Stereo Mixer*. Since I have imported different other projects, I cannot figure out which file is causing this error as well.

I import:

- a lot of *.MOV* files
- 6 AE projects
- some *png* and *jpeg*

What I tried so far:

- deleting the cache
- changes cache's location
- other projects work fine
- restart PC

Any ideas how I can debug/solve the problem?

Comment: If it is a corrupt file you could find which one thus: take half your clips offline by moving them to another folder. If the problem persists you then take half of the remaining clips offline, repeat. If it goes away, swap the files you just took offline back into the original folder and move the rest. Repeat until you've narrowed it down to one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try following this YouTube tutorial. What they do in it is make a new premiere pro project and then import the project into it.

Summary of video:

1. Open premiere pro and make a new project.
2. Go to the media browser
3. Navigate to where your project is saved
4. Right click on it and press import
5. Check import entire project and tick Create folder for imported items and click ok
6. Go to the tab where it says project:[*project name*]
7. Expand the folder there
8. Find the file  which has a icon which looks like lots of tracks on a timeline
9. Drag that into the timeline
10. Save the new project

Comment: Can you paraphrase what the video shows? That way if the video is no longer accessible, the answer will still be helpful.

Comment: Ok will do once I have time tonight.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman is that good now

Comment: @MichaelLiebman, If it looks good, why not upvote?

Comment: @RyanWeaver, the edit looked good. Unfortunately, I know nothing about whether it is the correct answer or not. If did know if it was right or if it had helped me, I definitely would have upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a similar problem and can't see the path, mount the long path to a shorter one. You can do this by sharing the folder, then mounting it as a drive letter.

Here's how to share it: http://lifehacker.com/5808814/how-to-share-a-folder-over-your-network-for-beginners

When you share the folder you can then mount it as a drive letter, so that the long path appears as an actual hard drive with its own drive letter.

Mapping a folder to a drive letter here: http://www.itworld.com/article/2694895/how-to-map-a-local-folder-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows.html

that should get you one step closer to find out what clip is causing the issues. But the issue itself might be a corrupted clip. Another thing that causes issues, if you have an extension of a file that does not represent that file. I.e. for some reason there is a .mov file but it's not a video or is a completely empty file.